# Https change document root via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I'm using this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L]
```

and it works OK in the httpdocs folder, but now we changed it to httpsdocs, because we want our whole site to be SSL encrypted and it doesn't work anymore. Any ideas on fixing it? thanks

Comment: Removed PHP tag since nothing to do with PHP - this is an .htaccess question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will convert any non-HTTPS requests to become HTTPS

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

ie. if you type in http://domain.com it will become https://domain.com - should work with the above still :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already done that and put that code in **httpdocs** folder so I am basically redirected to httpsdocs folder where I have the code which I have posted above and now I get a "This webpage has a redirect loop" and the website fails to load.

Comment: The problem was not in the htaccess but in my php code - I fixed that and now it works. Thanks again :)